# Is there a clear suggested path for migrating user fields from core 6 to 7 to 8?

Tags: users, upgrading

For those still migrating user data (e.g., interests, languages spoken, etc.) from Drupal 6, given the current status and plans for Drupal 8, is there a preferred way to manage those fields in Drupal 7?

With the discussions of seen about what should be in core or contributed and how profile fields should be treated in D8 I'm wondering if it would make sense to think ahead to the next major migration when considering whether to use Profile2.

Comment: I would go for fields on the user entity in Drupal 7 and start upgrading D6 to D7. That functionality exists in D7 core and will stay in D8 and above. Any "extra functionality" Profile2 may give you can be added afterwards. Most important is that the data structure is "robust" and "clean".